# Need recommendations for .Net data access layer for short time table project

Tags: .net, entity-framework, data-access-layer, strongly-typed-dataset

I have a .Net winforms project with a short time table (about a week or so).  I'm starting to code the data access layer.  It's not a huge job, about 20 tables, stored either in a Sql Server or local MS Access databases.  Data access is not my expertise so I'd like some recommendations.

My last experience was with .Net datasets and datatables, which gives an idea of how long it's been since I did this.  I'm aware that datasets are pretty obsolete at this point, and they can definitely be a royal pain at times.  I'm sure Entity Framework, nHibernate, Linq2SQL are all probably much better, and I want to use the best tool- but again, I have only a week.  If there's too large a learning curve then it might not be feasible.   Should I bite the bullet and stick with what I know (datasets), or is there a better tool that can be picked up and implemented fairly quickly?

Comment: .NET winforms, ASP, MVC?

Comment: Datasets and datatables are pretty much obsolete?  I'm way behind then, and I'm actively developing using them every day.

Comment: @Brad - .Net winforms, I edited the question.

Comment: @David - Are they not?  That makes me feel better.  But when I take to the internet, the majority opinion seems to be "avoid datasets whenever possible, use EF or nHib".  Which I'd be willing to try if I had enough time.

Comment: Go with what you know.  having one week to code something is a short enough timeline without having to deal with a learning curve.

Comment: For a lightweight ORM you could use ModuleStore http://code.google.com/p/bsn-modulestore/ (not as well known as the other biggies but still quite powerful). Nhibernate is also a contender and also Entity frameworks is also a decent contender. For speed and a short learning curve, I would go with EF.

Comment: rie819 does have a very valid point however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just finished writing a Datalayer in 'Code-First' POCO classes using the Entity Framework (beta 5.1, although it will work with 4.2+).

This means that you write your project entities in standard C# classes (asides from a few extra annotations such as what property should be a key) and you get very straightforward persistence. The Entity framework creates your SQL database, sets up all the tables and relationships so you can be up and running with a Data Access layer in next to no time. 
To store or retrieve objects you make a call to an (automatically created) object context, which feels like using LINQ to pull objects out of lists of your entities (in reality it is actually dynamically creating the SQL and querying the tables).

There is a little bit of configuration involved, but like the above it is straightforward.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/09/28/ef-4-2-code-first-walkthrough.aspx as a great tutorial

Comment: I'm *tentatively* scoring this as best answer.  My big concern was learning curve, but if EF provides an avenue for quick implementation then I suppose it's worth a shot.  I've never been in love with datasets anyways.  But it's tentative because given the week deadline, if progress bogs down after a day or two then I'm gonna have to fall back to what I know.

Answer (score 2):

There is a dizzying array of new tools available.  All of those are wonderful tools, really, but there's still nothing wrong with traditional ADO.NET. All of them use it under the hood, to one extent or another.

They provide wonderful tools like Object-Relational Mapping, and simplify things for us, but in some cases, they are overkill, and sometimes the right tool for the job is not the "cool new thing" but something that's tried and true.

In ***your*** case, given that you don't have time to learn new things, I really think it's best to go with what you know

Comment: You're right about there being plenty of tools- adds a little anxiety to picking the "right one" when you are on a tight schedule.  I'm gonna at least give EF a shot, but you could prove right, this might be too ambitious for a week's time.